# Parse Facebook Login - Javascript dialog box

Tags: parse-platform, facebook-login

I am using Parse.com and trying to implement their Facebook login functionality. I have the following code, and when I load the page a Facebook dialog pops up and immediately closes. No success or error message is given.

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Initialize Parse SDK
    Parse.initialize('xxx',
            'xxx');

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

        //Initialize Facebook SDK via Parse

        Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
            appId      : 'xxx',
            status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
            cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
        });

        // use Parse SDK to show Facebook login box on page load
        Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(null, {
            success: function(user) {
                if (!user.existed()) {
                    alert("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                } else {
                    alert("User logged in through Facebook!");
                }
            },
            error: function(user, error) {
                alert("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
            }
        });
    };

    // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't waiting for Parse.FacebookUtils.init() to finish before calling logIn